# PDF is not attached phonegap email composer

Tags: ios, cordova, email, ionic-framework

I'm using the following plugin to send an email from a iphone phongeap app (using ionic): https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer

Everything works fine except when I try to attach a pdf file saved to the device: When the email interface opens up, I can see the attached pdf (called test.pdf), but when the email arrives to the recipient, there's no PDF. Instead there's a attached txt file but without any content.

If I go window.replace(path to pdf) the PDF opens up, so I'm sure the PDF gets saved and that the path is correct. After reading this, https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer/issues/33, I have also tried to take away the path start (file://) and to replaace it with (relative://) but to no use. Would really appreciate any input on this: Here's the relevant code:

```
    var doc = new jsPDF();

    doc.text(20, 20, 'HELLO!');

    doc.setFont("courier");
    doc.setFontType("normal");
    doc.text(20, 30, 'This is a PDF document generated using JSPDF.');
    doc.text(20, 50, 'YES, Inside of PhoneGap!');

    var pdfOutput = doc.output();
    console.log( pdfOutput );


window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {



  fileSystem.root.getFile("test.pdf", {create: true}, function(entry) {
  var fileEntry = entry;
  console.log(entry);

  $scope.filepath =  fileEntry.toURL();

  $scope.filepath = $scope.filepath.replace('file\:\/\/', 'relative://');




    $scope.emailer($scope.filepath);    


     //  window.location.href = $scope.filepath;




  entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
     writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
     console.log("write success");
  };

  console.log("writing to file");
     writer.write( pdfOutput );
  }, function(error) {
     console.log(error);
  });

  }, function(error){
   console.log(error);
 });





},
function(event){
 console.log( evt.target.error.code );
 });



    $scope.emailer = function(file) {


    alert(file);



    window.plugin.email.open({
            to:      ['info@appplant.de'],
            subject: 'Congratulations',
            body:    '<h1>Happy Birthday!!!</h1>',
            attachments: [file]     
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

We are using the exact same plugin and have it working, the URL we use looks like this

/var/mobile/Applications/998AEF02-5D26-4064-BC7D-A94A218609C5/Documents/yourpdffilenamehere.pdf

The URL is returned to our app from a pdf-plugin we use.

Comment: Ok, thank's for replying! If I alert my path on the actual device I get: cdvfile://localhost/persistent/test.pdf, and on the simulator: var/mobile/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/D781404D-5C5A-4458-ABAD-9741355D9060/Documents/test.pdf. None of them work though. Do you know why the I get the cdvfile:... on the phone and iff this is a problem?